# Export Orders from Magento MySQL DB without Magento

Tags: orders, database, export

I have an old Magento database file, but the files associated with it are gone.

The database file is for Magento 7.02

I need to export the orders with the line items and a description of the item from the database.

Does anyone have a way that I can get this data from the database extract, without having the original files for Magento itself?

Fields:
Order - 
Order ID, Customer Name, Email, Order Date, Amount

OrderContents - 
OrderId, LineItem, Name, Description, Cost

Anyone have a good idea to extract the data?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The involved tables are:

- `sales_flat_order` - for base order data such as Order ID, date and
  total amounts;
- `sales_flat_order_address` - to retrieve customer data
  (unless the order is related to a virtual/downloadable product, there
  are two rows per order, respectively the billing and the shipping
  address);
- `sales_flat_order_item` - to retrieve order contents; the number of rows (items) depends on the product types; pay attention to the items with a not null `parent_item_id` value which means that a particular product type (such as a configurable) was ordered; for the type of data you want to retrieve you should find it in parent item rather than in child one;

There are other tables related to the order that contain data you don't seem to need:

- `sales_flat_order_payment`
- `sales_flat_order_status_history`
- `sales_order_tax`
- `sales_order_tax_item`
- `sales_payment_transaction`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do not want magento files. i would recommend following apporach

1) Take fresh Magento of the same version as the database.

2) Change setting in local.xml with the database you have

3) install this module

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

Which would export all the order in csv format and you can use the same format to import into newer version.

Hope this will help